# How to view tables in sql?

Tags: sql, database, database-connection, navicat

Hai i am a beginner of Database,

i have a .sql file which contains some tables of data, i want to know how to import them and how to view the list of tables.

presently im using the following:-

software or editor : navicat lite
server : localhost.
databse file format: .sql

Comment: And what database are you using? .sql files are typically scripts not datbase tables.

Comment: im presently using mysql datbase

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to execute the script in sql server, then type

```
select * from [database_name].information_schema.tables
```

to view tables and relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a sql file is not really a database, it is a script.  You can run the script from any tool, but I'd use command line.  This is navicat connected to mysql?

mysql -u username -p databasename < script.sql
password: ****

And then the results can be seen using navicat or any other tool

Answer (score 0):

If the .sql file has statements such as "CREATE TABLE..." and then later on "INSERT INTO..." then the script is possibly creating the tables and inserting the data.

To allow that to happen, the tables need to not exist in the database. You can then run the script and it will create the tables and fill in the data.

If the tables do exist, you can always either delete them, or change the CREATE to an ALTER and the script should then run.

Hope that helps.